# I've tried to export from Photos to hard drive but it says my Mac Hard Drive is in "read" only mode How change so I can export?

Tags: hard-drive, photos, video

Took me forever how to finally figure out how to export photos/videos from the new Photos app to an external hard drive - which I must do to free up space as I have over 100 gig of footage I've shot of my 100 year old grandma - with more to shoot.

It says my Macintosh Hard Drive is in 'read' only mode so it won't let me export.

Can you tell me how to change that so it can allow me to export and I can move these asap?

Comment: There is no need to shout (type in all caps) as your question will be read regardless, may not get answered but will be read anyway.  Exporting from the Photos Library to the Macintosh HD doesn't free up any space, you need to export to another drive to then remove them from the Photos Library to actually free up space on the Macintosh HD.  Is it only in Photos that it's saying the HD is R/O, can you save things in other apps to the internal HD?  Also, where on the internal drive were you trying to export them to?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If you are running OS X 10.10 "Yosemite" or earlier, see [this Apple support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201560).

Comment: Adding an image with words doesn’t change the fact that this a link only answe